# HTTP Auth vs Complex URL

Tags: http, security, https, http-authentication

Imagine I need to provide a secure endpoint with private data. Consider `user1` with `password1234`. Is there any difference in security between:

1. https://website.com/myendpoint/user1/password1234
2. https://website.com/myendpoint with HTTP Basic Auth with credentials given above

It seems to me there is in fact no difference, but I don't have any specific/strong arguments for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a significant difference. As per the best practice, you should not include any sensitive information (let alone passwords) in the url.
Reasons are the following:

- Urls get logged on the server (typically to files, but other datastores might even be worse) which might allow an attacker to extract this data, think for example backups as well.
- Urls might get logged and/or inspected on intermediate proxies. Consider corporate proxies with https inspection.
- Urls are cached on the client and added to browser history. A script or a malicious user having gained access to a pc might extract passwords from there. Even if the intended client is programmatic, consider users who want to use your app or api from a browser for whatever reason (users are very creative :) ).
- Urls might be seen on screen.

Of course not all of these apply to all usecases, but some of these you have no control over. So it's best to not include any sensitive data in your urls. Http basic over https is much better.